# How many lines of symmetry does a regular octagon have?

Tags: geometry

I can do this problem by drawing a picture and lines of symmetry. My question about this problem is what if it is not an octagon, but any regular polygon. What is a simple way to solve the problem?

Problem: How many lines of symmetry does a regular octagon have?

Comment: I'm not sure about your background but the study of symmetry in mathematics often uses the language of abstract algebra. Consider looking up Symmetry Groups and see where you get from there ;)

Comment: Drawing the picture is the right way to start. If you do that for a triangle, square, pentagon, ..., octagon you should see the pattern. (It's a little easier  for odd-gons than for even-gons.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there is 8 .
Drawing an octagon is best but if you want to do without it , imagine drawing symmetric lines inbetween the lines of the Octagon or you can imagine drawing lines at the point where of the 2 lines meet.

Lines drawn inbetween lines = 4
Lines drawn where 2 points meet = 4
Total = 8

Comment: Can you provide a picture showing how you reach that answer?

Answer (score 0):

For n-gons there is always $n$ lines of symmetry. Draw different polygons and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

For n-gons there are always $2n$ symmetries in total; $n$ reflections and $n$ rotations. So in this case there are 16 symmetries in total, 8 reflections and 8 rotations.

A nice way to think about this is to consider where you can put each vertex. A symmetry is any permutation that preserves adjacency of vertices. Label the vertices 1 through to 8, then you have 8 choices for where to put the first vertex, 2 for the next and only 1 after that. Thus we have 16 symmetries.

If you want more information on this look up Dihedral groups.

Answer (score 0):

My answer I got was 10 because if you draw lines threw the octagon because it will explain more to you.
             - forth grader advice